# Carregar chart com 2 store um para o axes e outro para series

Tags: javascript

Crie um *chart* do tipo Line, para ele vou poder carregar um ou mais tipos de series dentro desse mesmo gráfico.
Mais nesse caso somente dois series como no link.

Fiz no `listeners->painted` para renderizar o gráfico.
A legenda consigo carregar dinamicamente de boa. mais as linhas não aparecem

Segue código da View, tem dois links com os dados em *json*.

`prntscr.com/80vj9p` ---- nesse eu carrego o *graficoIndBIStore* no caso seria as duas linhas do gráfico e as duas legendas

`prntscr.com/80vkis`  ---- nesse eu carrego os valores do gráfico mais, não carrega as linhas ficam no canto superior esquerdo

Imagem da view do gráfico `prntscr.com/80vovv`

```js
Ext.define('Integrator.view.BI.Chart.Line', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.linechart',
    requires: ['Ext.chart.axis.Numeric', 'Ext.data.JsonStore', 'Ext.chart.CartesianChart'],
    
    config: {
        cls: 'card4',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'chart',
                id: 'chartBILine',
                store: {},
                background: 'white',
                animate: true,
                legend:{
                    position: 'bottom'
                }                
            }
        ],
        listeners: {
            painted: function () {
                var indicadorStore = Ext.getStore('biChartsStore'),
                    graficoIndBIStore = Ext.getStore('GraficoIndBIStore'),
                    chart = Ext.getCmp('chartBILine'),
                    seriesArray = new Array(),
                    axesArray = new Array(),
                    fields = new Array(),
                    lineColors = ['#115fa6', '#94ae0a', '#a61120', '#006600', '#ff9900', '#ff9999', '#ffccff', '#66ff00', '#cc33ff'],
                    markerColors = ['#94ae0a', '#a61120', '#115fa6', '#003300', '#006600', '#0066ff', '#993300', '#66ff00', '#cc33ff'];                            
                                               
                graficoIndBIStore.each(function(rec, index){                                        
                    seriesArray.push(
                        new Ext.chart.series.Line({
                            type: 'line',
                            xField: 'data',
                            yField: [rec.data.titulo_ind],                                                                                   
                            stacked: false,
                            style: {
                                smooth: true,
                                stroke: lineColors[index - 0],
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
                                shadowBlur: 10,
                                shadowOffsetX: 3,
                                shadowOffsetY: 3
                            },
                            marker: {
                                type: 'circle',
                                stroke: markerColors[index - 0],
                                fill: markerColors[index - 0],
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                radius: 4,
                                shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
                                shadowBlur: 10,
                                shadowOffsetX: 3,
                                shadowOffsetY: 3,
                                fx: {
                                    duration: 300
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    );                                
                });
                
                indicadorStore.each(function(rec2, index2){
                    fields.push(rec2.data.valor);
                });
                                                
                axesArray.push(
                    new Ext.chart.axis.Numeric({
                        type: 'numeric',
                        position: 'left',
                        fields: fields,
                        title: 'Valor',
                        minorTickSteps: 1,
                        grid: {
                            odd: {
                                opacity: 1,
                                fill: '#ddd'
                            }
                        },
                        style: {
                            axisLine: false,
                            estStepSize: 20,
                            stroke: '#ddd',
                            'stroke-width': 0.5
                        }
                    })
                );
                
                axesArray.push(
                    new Ext.chart.axis.Category({
                        type: 'category',
                        position: 'bottom',
                        fields: ['data'],
                        title: {
                            text: 'Meses',
                            fontSize: !Ext.os.is.Phone ? 15 : 10
                        },
                        style: {
                            estStepSize: 1,
                            stroke: '#999'
                        },
                        label: {
                            rotate: { degrees: 65 }
                        }
                    })
                );
                
                var data = {"data": indicadorStore.getData().items};
                chart.setStore(data);
                
                chart.setAxes(axesArray);
                chart.setSeries(seriesArray);
            }
        }
    }
});
```